# How to show product custom attribute in sales item ordered section in admin for bundle product and configurable product in Magento2.2.0?

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I want to show product custom attribute in sales item ordered section in admin for **Bundle product** and **Configurable product** in Magento2.2.0? 
Refer my screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for Configurable product, Crete a Model then in layout

> sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="SahiSdi_Invoiceattribute::items/column/name.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

then in Template

> name.phtml

```
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>

<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()->load($_item->getProductId());

$_code = 'custom_attribute ';
$product_type = $product->getTypeId();
if(!empty($product_type) && $product_type == 'configurable'){
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $simpleProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku());
  $child_product = $simpleProduct->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($simpleProduct);
    if(!empty($child_product)){
      $_attributeValue = $child_product; 
    }
}else{
  $_attributeValue = $product->getData($_code);
}
?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('SKU') ?>:</span> <?= implode('<br />', $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))) ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <dt><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['label'] ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['value'] ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid() ?>"> ...</span><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id = 'id' . uniqid() ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
                            <script>
                                require(['prototype'], function() {
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').show();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').show();});
                                });
                            </script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php //Your code starts to show custom attribute value ?>
    <?php if(!empty($_attributeValue )){ ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <dt><?= __('Custom Attribute ') ?>:</dt>
            <dd><?php echo $_attributeValue ; ?></dd>
        </dl>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php //Your code ends to show custom attribute value ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Fernandus, its working perfectly fine:)

Comment: I will try to get them for Bundle

Comment: Thanks Fernandus, I will be waiting for your answer.